# How do I get specific values from a NSIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsinteger, nsindexpath

I have a NSArray with NSIndexPaths inside of it

```
NSArray *array = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

The NSLog returns this:

```
<NSIndexPath 0x5772fc0> 2 indexes [0, 0]
<NSIndexPath 0x577cfa0> 2 indexes [0, 1]
<NSIndexPath 0x577dfa0> 2 indexes [0, 2]
```

I am trying to get the second value from the indexPath into just a plain NSInteger

Comment: Is this really your code? Are you using a custom table view subclass? I don't think there's a method called `indexPathsForSelectedRows`. You also can't just assign an `NSIndexPath` instance to an `NSArray` pointer.

Comment: Apple has undocumented methods for multiselection in a UITableView(like the mail app) that is where indexPathsForSelectedRows comes from

Comment: As of iOS 5 this code is 100% app store safe! (not that I care, I'm hell post-SDK)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `NSIndexPath`'s `-indexAtPosition:` method to get the last index:

```
NSIndexPath *path = ...; // Initialize the path.
NSUInteger lastIndex = [path indexAtPosition:[path length] - 1]; // Gets you the '2' in [0, 2]
```

In your case, you can use the following (as Josh mentioned in his comment, I'm assuming you're working with a custom subclass of `UITableView`, because it doesn't have that specific method (`-indexPathsForSelectedRows:`)):

```
NSArray *indexes = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
for (NSIndexPath *path in indexes) {
    NSUInteger index = [path indexAtPosition:[path length] - 1];
    NSLog(@"%lu", index);
}
```

That will print out `0, 1, 2, ...`.

Comment: You can also do `path.row` to get the value at the index